# How to specify font URL to GoFPDF font?

Tags: go, pdf

I want to use a custom font to generate pdf with gofpdf. Here is what I'm using :

```
fontPath := filepath.Join(cfg.Path, "assets", "font", "oxygen.ttf")
log.Println(fontPath)

doc.AddUTF8Font("oxygen", "", fontPath)
doc.SetFont("oxygen", "", 12)
```

> /home/username/myapp/assets/font/oxygen.ttf

However pdf generations throws this error which I struggle to understand :

> stat home/username/myapp/assets/font/oxygen.ttf: no such file or directory

Eventually I did check the stat myself through :

```
stat /home/username/myapp/assets/font/oxygen.ttf
```

The file exists properly and stats displays its infos. But it's like gofpdf ignores the initial slash (based on the error thrown). How to refer to the file URL properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**solved**

Should have read the doc more accurately. Font dir has to be specified when creating the fpdf doc. To me it was :

```
gofpdf.New(orientation, "mm", "A4", "")
```

to

```
gofpdf.New(orientation, "mm", "A4", filepath.Join(cfg.Path, "assets", "font"))
```

then we can use :

```
doc.AddUTF8Font("oxygen", "", "oxygen.ttf")
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve the import problem like this:

`pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "./internal/delivery/rpc/rpcs")`

and

`pdf.AddUTF8Font("IRANSansk", "", "./font/IRANSansWeb.ttf")`

now the import problem is gone