# I need help about dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, fonts, dockerfile

i need help now
my project are golang server
this server are create pdf file(github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf)
and i am use korean font file(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nanum+Gothic)
i can see good result pdf file

but make a docker image after i can see error message
(err: stat go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf: no such file or directory)

why? i am copy at docker file

```
COPY /cert/Wildcard.sunmediscreen.com.key.pem /go/src/pdf.server/cert/
COPY /cert/Full_Wildcard.sunmediscreen.com.pem /go/src/pdf.server/cert/

COPY /templates/font/NanumGothic-Bold.ttf /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/
COPY /templates/font/NanumGothic-ExtraBold.ttf /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/
COPY /templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/
```

this is a dockerfile log

```
Step 21/28 : COPY /cert/Wildcard.sunmediscreen.com.key.pem /go/src/pdf.server/cert/
 ---> b4e2c2a498f0
Step 22/28 : COPY /cert/Full_Wildcard.sunmediscreen.com.pem /go/src/pdf.server/cert/
 ---> eb613bcfd946
Step 23/28 : COPY /templates/font/NanumGothic-Bold.ttf /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/
 ---> 292667b551ec
Step 24/28 : COPY /templates/font/NanumGothic-ExtraBold.ttf /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/
 ---> e9d027f3cefb
Step 25/28 : COPY /templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/
 ---> 2a9c96090552
```

and this is a golang

```
fontDir := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("GOPATH"), "src/pdf.server/templates/font")
    pdf.AddUTF8Font("NanumGothic", "", filepath.Join(fontDir, "NanumGothic-Regular.ttf"))
    pdf.AddUTF8Font("NanumGothic", "B", filepath.Join(fontDir, "NanumGothic-Bold.ttf"))
    pdf.AddUTF8Font("NanumGothic", "EB", filepath.Join(fontDir, "NanumGothic-ExtraBold.ttf"))
```

just font file has a problem

please help me

---

os.Getenv("GOPATH")
this path are no problem
because pem file path has not problem about tls setting

crtpath := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("GOPATH"), "src/pdf.server/cert/Full_Wildcard.sunmediscreen.com.pem")
keypath := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("GOPATH"), "src/pdf.server/cert/Wildcard.sunmediscreen.com.key.pem")

```
var x509 tls.Certificate
x509, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(crtpath, keypath)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: You could try to print out `os.Getenv("GOPATH")` in your program, and make sure the fonts has been installed correctly in docker container.

Comment: os.Getenv("GOPATH")
this path are no problem 
because pem file path has not problem about tls setting

Comment: What user are you running the `COPY` commands as, and what user are you running the server as? It could be a permissions issue if you're copying as root but running as a non-root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path in `err: stat go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf: no such file or directory` missed the root directory `/`, it should be `/go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf`.

```golang
fmt.Println(os.Stat("go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf"))
fmt.Println(os.Stat("/go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf"))
```

output:

```
<nil> stat go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf: no such file or directory
<nil> stat /go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf: no such file or directory
```

Comment: this is just err log err: stat go/src/pdf.server/templates/font/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf: no such file or directory i add root directory(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "src/pdf.server/templates/font" + "NanumGothic-Regular.ttf")

Comment: this is good answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724418/how-to-specify-font-url-to-gofpdf-font